# MATLAB importdata with multiple files

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to import multiple data files in MATLAB by using `importdata` so that the data are available outside the loop:

```
for i = 1:5
    filename = sprintf('data-%d.txt', i);
    data{i} = importdata(filename);
end
```

But the script returns the following error:

```
Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Error in process (line 12)
    data{i} = importdata(filename);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error typically appears when you are trying to make a cell assignment to a variable that is already instantiated as a non-cell type.

Most likely, somewhere earlier in your code you initialized `data` as a matrix and you are now attempting to address it as though it is a cell type.

To quickly test this theory out, try out this slightly modified code which ensures that `data` will be initialized as cell type when you try to address it.

```
data = cell(1);
for i = 1:5
    filename = sprintf('data-%d.txt', i);
    data{i} = importdata(filename);
end
```